# Pc reboots while connected to a UPS and no power failure

Tags: ups

UPS model: TRV NEO 850
power factor is 0.6
220V
transfer time is 2/4 ms

i have the ups connected via usb and the monitoring software show no problems at all (battery ok, ups load no more than 70% maybe the cause?), i have 1 pc and 1 monitor connected to ups

Comment: You might describe the frequency of your reboots - one time, 2 times a day, during the boot phase....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the Power Factor 60% ?  That might be true of a lightly loaded AC Motor. But an efficient Computer (or Electronic) Power Supply should be much better than 60%.

> **Possible answer on review of specifications:**
>
> http://www.trv.com.ar/detalle-shop.php?cd=11
>
> Power Factor 60% measured at Input not Output meaning it is
> inefficient.

70% static ongoing load should be OK for a high quality UPS.

Check the waveform of the UPS (look at the documentation). A good UPS will have a good sine wave output. Cheaper UPS units have a hash waveform that the manufacturer claims approximates 117 volts RMS  (or your country's nominal voltage).  At 70% load, the voltage may not be correct. You need a (digital) voltmeter to check this point.

> **Note:**  Specifications say the UPS shuts down if overloaded. It may be tripping up your computer. Try reducing overall load to 50% or a
> bit less.
>
> The specifications also say it is a hash output waveform.

Is this a bargain basement UPS?  Cheap electronics tend to provide what you pay for, so be cautious about this point.

Is the UPS under warranty? If so, return for replacement or warranty service.

The situation is NOT normal. My Desktop is on UPS (and has been for years) and never reboots when the power fails and the UPS kicks in, or just connected to the UPS.

Check your computer on your home mains and not on the UPS. If it works OK that way, then the UPS may need service.

Comment: power factor is 0.6 according to the manufacturer manual, so basicaly you're saying the ups might be overloaded? and actually isnt a bargain ups I've had it for almost a year now

Comment: That is a strange PF number for an ordinary circuit. I have measured Power Factor myself, and only motors (in my household stuff) do that. I think it is possible a 70% load could overload it that way. Remove the monitor and everything else but the computer, restart the computer (to normalize its load) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: sure thing gonna try it now also here you have the link to the ups manufacture manual maybe you can find some useful information

http://www.trv.com.ar/detalle-shop.php?cd=11

Comment: Power factor is on input not output and I amended my answer.  Overload shuts the UPS OFF and may be tripping up your computer. Try reducing the load.

Comment: worked well for almost a year why suddenly it wouldn't work? let me see if with only the computer works well

Comment: Yes. I also amended to note that the computer should be tested on regular mains (not UPS) and it that works, the UPS may need service.

Comment: seems to be working good now, just to know whats the power factor on output in this ups? and aprox on what ups load % do u think the reboot is happening? (also thank u so much for the help and for the anwsers :D )

Comment: The power factor was on input not output.  You might mark my answer as "helpful" as it seems to be helping you.

Comment: done, thank u so much again